# How to repeat my user entered string by the user input number

Tags: c, string

I need to multiply the string by the number entered by the user.

For example, if he enters "hello" and he types 3, it must show `hellohellohello`

```
 int multStr() {

   char string;
   int multiply = 0;
   int j;

   printf("enter a string please");
   scanf("%s", & string);
   printf("now multiply your string");
   scanf("%d", & multiply);
   for (j = 0; multiply == !j; ++j) {
     printf("%s", string);
   }
 }
```

But nothing is printed out, can i please get help?

Comment: Use `j < multiply`. Also string is just a single character, change it to something like `char string[100];` and remove the `&` before it in `scanf`

Comment: The reason it runs but then nothing happens is, by the way, that malformed comparison `multiply==!j;`. It is nowhere near "not equal to" (my closest guess to what that was supposed to be ...) but it actually compiles as `multiply == !j`. `j` starts out as `0` and so `!j == 1`. Unless you happen to enter `1` as the value for `multiply`, this will evaluate to `false` and the loop terminates immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you got some bugs:

char string[100];//change to pointer

scanf("%s", &string);change this to --->gets_s(string,100)

for (j = 0; multiply>j; ++j)//change the condition

Hope this helped you and good luck later